# Jenkins Maven compilation fails due to JDK features unsupported?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Whenever I deploy a Jenkins build with Maven, it says that I have the 1.3 JDK, even though I have 1.7 installed.

Here is a picture of the error log I get when using an enhanced for loop:

http://gyazo.com/d1c7e297199dbf8a8b6ba23efa5733ba.png

However, I clearly have 1.7 JDK installed.

http://gyazo.com/27b85ba9ea25579aa714b0e2586fd618.png

If anyone knows why this issue occurs and how to fix it, please post below.

Sorry I don't have a ton of formatted information, but I have no idea why this could possibly be happening as I do not have such an outdated JDK and have the most recent updates from Oracle. Maven and Jenkins are also updated completely.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have the $JAVA_HOME setting, check which Java is on the PATH, check the global configuration of Jenkins which Java it uses. Those come into my mind at first.

Comment: what does your maven-compiler-plugin configuration look like in your POM?

Answer (score 1):

The complaint of maven is not about your jdk version, but about the -source parameter of the compiler. Older Maven versions use a version of the maven-compiler-plugin, which uses -source and -target 1.3 by default.

So, what you need to do is configure you project to use higher source and target levels in order to use your for each loop:

(taken from https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Note that simply setting the version of the maven-compiler-plugin would actually be sufficient, since for version 3.1 the default *is* 1.5, however it is good style to explicitly include the source and target version in your master pom.

Answer (score 0):

You have the project set to compile with the default jdk according to your stack trace. Your default is your %JAVA_HOME% environment variable on the server which is probably set to an older jdk. In order to compile with the 1.7 jdk you have to specify this in your project config. Change jdk : (Default) to your 1.7 name.. which is jdk.

Or you can just go to the maven jdk and change it from (inherit from project) to jdk.

There is already an issue ticket open with jenkins related to this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-755